# How do I use the kendo react gridcolumnmenu filter to filter a grid column that uses a custom grid cell with a dropdown list

Tags: reactjs, kendo-ui

I have a kendo react grid that I am using the gridcolumnmenu on. I am using the gridcolumnmenufilter component in it and the filter works fine for the majority of my columns, however some columns are edited with a dropdown list, this is causing issues in the filtering. The built in filter is looking at the value of those dropdown lists and not the text which is causing unwanted filtering behavior. How do I make the filter look to the text field of the dropdown and not the value field?
This is my custom grid cell code:

`

```
const StatusDropDownListCell = (props) => {
  const { dataItem } = props;
  const field = props.field || "";
  const statusData = filterBy(props.data, {
    logic: 'and',
    filters: [
      { field: "grouping", operator: "eq", value: dataItem.ActionGroup, ignoreCase: true }
    ]
  });
  return (
    dataItem.inEdit ?
      <td className={props.className} style={props.style} role={"gridcell"}>
        <DropDownList
          data={statusData}
          textField="text"
          valueField="value"
          value={statusData.find((c) => c.value === dataItem.ActionStatusId)}
          onChange={(e) => props.onChange(dataItem.Id, field, e.target.value)}
        />
      </td> : <td className={props.className} style={props.style} role={"gridcell"}>{props.dataItem.ActionStatus}</td>
  );
};
```

`

Here is my column menu implementation:

`

```
const ColumnMenu = (props) => {
  //console.log(props);
  return (
    <div>
      <GridColumnMenuSort {...props} />
      <GridColumnMenuFilter {...props}/>
      <GridColumnMenuGroup {...props} />
      <GridColumnMenuItemGroup>
        <GridColumnMenuItemContent show={true}>
          <div className={"k-column-list-wrapper"}>
            <div className={"k-column-list"}>
              <div
                className={classNames("k-column-list-item", {
                  "k-disabled": props.columnLocked,
                })}
                onClick={() => props.onToggleColumnLock()}
              >
                <span className="k-icon k-i-lock" /> Lock Column
              </div>
              <div
                className={classNames("k-column-list-item", {
                  "k-disabled": !props.columnLocked,
                })}
                onClick={() => props.onToggleColumnLock()}
              >
                <span className="k-icon k-i-unlock" /> Unlock Column
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </GridColumnMenuItemContent>
      </GridColumnMenuItemGroup>
    </div>
  )
}
```

`

and the column in question:

`

```
<Column 
        field="ActionStatusId" 
        title="Status" 
        width="200px" 
        locked={columnMenuOptions.ActionStatusId} 
        groupHeaderTemplate={groupHeaderTemplate}
        columnMenu={(props) => (
          <ColumnMenu
            {...props}
            columnLocked={columnMenuOptions.ActionStatusId}
            field="ActionStatus"
            gridFilterCell={CustomGridMenuFilter}
            onToggleColumnLock={() =>
              toggleColumnLock("ActionStatusId")
            }
          />
        )}
        cell={(props) => (
          <StatusDropDownListCell
            data={actionStatus}
            dataItem={props.dataItem}
            onChange={handleStatusItemChange}
            field="ActionStatusId"
            groupField="grouping"
            className={props.className}
            style={props.style}
          />
        )} 
      />
```

`

Any help would be appreciated.